# Multiple checkboxes using v-for vue ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I wanted to get the checkboxes values and store it in an array using v-model, the first instance I toggle a check it doesn't register but when I check a second one and hit submit the second value registers, another problem is that when I try to select multiple checkboxes it only logs the recently checked box after triggering the handleClick function.
I've also tried console logging filter.filtProv and it only logs the recently checked.

```
//vue app
var filter = {
  filtProv: reactive([]) as String[]
}
var temp: any = []

let handleClick = () =>{
  temp.push(filter.filtProv)
  console.log(temp)
}


//template
<div id="checkboxes" v-for="provider in providerList" v-bind:key="provider" class="m-2">
   <input class="mx-1" type="checkbox" :value="provider" v-model="filter.filtProv"/>
   <label>{{provider}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding a checked parameter in your `providerList` objects.

For example **:**

```
{
  value: string,
  checked: boolean
}
```

And then at the end on submit you can filtered out the `checked` objects from the array.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    providerList: [{
        value: 'first checkbox',
      checked: false
    }, {
        value: 'Second checkbox',
      checked: false
    }, {
        value: 'Third checkbox',
      checked: false
    }, {
        value: 'Fourth checkbox',
      checked: false
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      const result = this.providerList.filter((obj) => obj.checked).map((obj) => obj.value);
      console.log(result);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="checkboxes" v-for="(provider, index) in providerList" v-bind:key="index" class="m-2">
    <input class="mx-1" type="checkbox" :value="provider.value" v-model="provider.checked"/>
    <label>{{provider.value}}</label>
  </div><br>
  <button @click="submitForm()">Submit!</button>
</div>
```